# python syntax hilighting using Pygment program

Tags: python, html, css, pygments, codehighlighter

so, I have this test mardown document, and I used python to generate HTML doc like this:

```
python -m markdown -x codehilite mydoc.md > mydoc.html
```

Then, I generated the CSS file using Pygment as below:

```
pygmentize -S default -f html > codehilite.css
```

And, then I added the link to this CSS file into mydoc.html, however, the resulting HTML document still doesn't fully highlight python codes. The strings embeded in "" are highlithed, but import, and print functions are not, as shown in this picture:

[image]

Here is my mardown file: (mydoc.md)

```
This is a test

    import numpy
    print ("Hello world!")
```

And here is my HTML doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./codehilite.css">
</head>

<body>

<p>This is a test</p>
<div class="codehilite"><pre><span class="n">import</span> <span class="n">numpy</span>
<span class="n">print</span> <span class="p">(</span><span class="s">&quot;Hello world!&quot;</span><span class="p">)</span>
</pre></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and codehilite.css contains:

```
.hll { background-color: #ffffcc }
.c { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment */
.err { border: 1px solid #FF0000 } /* Error */
.k { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword */
.o { color: #666666 } /* Operator */
.cm { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment.Multiline */
.cp { color: #BC7A00 } /* Comment.Preproc */
.c1 { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment.Single */
.cs { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment.Special */
.gd { color: #A00000 } /* Generic.Deleted */
.ge { font-style: italic } /* Generic.Emph */
.gr { color: #FF0000 } /* Generic.Error */
.gh { color: #000080; font-weight: bold } /* Generic.Heading */
.gi { color: #00A000 } /* Generic.Inserted */
.go { color: #808080 } /* Generic.Output */
.gp { color: #000080; font-weight: bold } /* Generic.Prompt */
.gs { font-weight: bold } /* Generic.Strong */
.gu { color: #800080; font-weight: bold } /* Generic.Subheading */
.gt { color: #0040D0 } /* Generic.Traceback */
.kc { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Constant */
.kd { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Declaration */
.kn { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Namespace */
.kp { color: #008000 } /* Keyword.Pseudo */
.kr { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Reserved */
.kt { color: #B00040 } /* Keyword.Type */
.m { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number */
.s { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String */
.na { color: #7D9029 } /* Name.Attribute */
.nb { color: #008000 } /* Name.Builtin */
.nc { color: #0000FF; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Class */
.no { color: #880000 } /* Name.Constant */
.nd { color: #AA22FF } /* Name.Decorator */
.ni { color: #999999; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Entity */
.ne { color: #D2413A; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Exception */
.nf { color: #0000FF } /* Name.Function */
.nl { color: #A0A000 } /* Name.Label */
.nn { color: #0000FF; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Namespace */
.nt { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Tag */
.nv { color: #19177C } /* Name.Variable */
.ow { color: #AA22FF; font-weight: bold } /* Operator.Word */
.w { color: #bbbbbb } /* Text.Whitespace */
.mf { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Float */
.mh { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Hex */
.mi { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Integer */
.mo { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Oct */
.sb { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Backtick */
.sc { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Char */
.sd { color: #BA2121; font-style: italic } /* Literal.String.Doc */
.s2 { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Double */
.se { color: #BB6622; font-weight: bold } /* Literal.String.Escape */
.sh { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Heredoc */
.si { color: #BB6688; font-weight: bold } /* Literal.String.Interpol */
.sx { color: #008000 } /* Literal.String.Other */
.sr { color: #BB6688 } /* Literal.String.Regex */
.s1 { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Single */
.ss { color: #19177C } /* Literal.String.Symbol */
.bp { color: #008000 } /* Name.Builtin.Pseudo */
.vc { color: #19177C } /* Name.Variable.Class */
.vg { color: #19177C } /* Name.Variable.Global */
.vi { color: #19177C } /* Name.Variable.Instance */
.il { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Integer.Long */
```

Comment: what does `codehilite.css` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the language explicitly, since the auto guessing is not always reliable, e.g.,

```
:::python
    print("Hello, World")
    a = 1 + 2
```

That should solve your problem ;)